# Empurrar uma tag para o remoto

Tags: git

Estou precisando empurrar para o meu repositório remoto uma única tag, `v0.0.1`.

Eu sei que existe o `git push --tags`, porém esse comando, [conforme sua documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---tags), empurra todas as tags.

Qual o comando para empurrar uma única tag para o repositório remoto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use, [conforme a documentação](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_sharing_tags):

```
git push origin <nome-da-tag>
```

No git, tags e branches são muito parecidos, ambos são ponteiros para commits específicos. Por isso, a sintaxe para `push` é a mesma.